# Is this unnecessary warning?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a following static method in one of my utility class

```
+ (UIImage *) getImage:(NSURL*) fromUrl { //Warning here
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fromUrl];
    UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:urlData] autorelease];
    return image;
}
```

For this method I'm receiving a bellow warning message

> warning: incompatible Objective-C
>   types initializing 'struct NSURL *',
>   expected 'struct NSString *'

I did not noticed any exception, is this something I can ignore? Or how can I fix it?

Comment: How do you call `+getImage:`?

Comment: @KennyTM see Dave's answer...

Comment: There are no unnecessary warnings. And even if it's technically correct and the compiler prints a warning, it's still wrong because the compiler does not recognize it's correct. Make it clear to him and you're good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The warning is correct in that there is a conflicting type and, as with all warnings, you should fix it.

More likely than not, you have two `getImage:` methods declared, one that takes an `NSString` and one that takes an `NSURL` as their sole argument.   In Objective-C, the method namespace is flat and the recommended pattern is that there be only one declared argumentation for any given selector.

There is a more subtle issue, though.  `getImage:` is not really as descriptive as it either could be nor as descriptive as standard practice would dictate.

A better method declaration would be:

```
+ (UIImage *) imageFromURL: (NSURL *) anURL;
```

More descriptive. Less ambiguous.

Comment: Interesting! btw SO asking me to wait for 5min to accept answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably doing this:

```
UIImage * image = [MyUtilityClass getImage:@"http://example.com/image.jpg"];
```

You should be doing this:

```
UIImage * image = [MyUtilityClass getImage:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/image.jpg"]];
```

(ignoring naming conventions....)

Comment: If he was doing that, it'd have thrown an exception, I would bet.